# centOS is not reading windows8 partition while installing

Tags: windows-8, installation, centos-6

I am installing centOS over windows 8 in dual boot mode. And I made 30GB free space through windows partition. But when I install centOS , it is not reading that partitions. It shows full hard-disk.
Is there any solution?
Actually I dont want to remove my windows and there is lots of data too.How could I do this?

Any help would appreciated.

Thanks!!